# Multiple colours to Bar Charts Swift one above the other

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, charts

I am using CHARTS library in swift.
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

I got suceess in creating Pie chart and bar chart.
Now I want to create bar chart with one "x" value and 2 "y" values.

I created the bar chart with two different values.
But I am not able to set the colours for them
I passed the colour array to delegate method `setColors` but it takes the last colour from the array.

Can any one please guide me for having different colours on bar chart.

Here is my code to call BarChart library

```
months = ["HR","Operations","iOS","Android","PHP","Support","Testing","Designer"]
        let unitsSold = [10.0,20.0,30.0,20.0,20.0,10.0,15.0,20.0]
        let unitsSold1 = [20.0,30.0,50.0,40.0,30.0,20.0,45.0,50.0]

        let barChartClass = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BarChartViewControllerID") as! BarChartViewController
        self.addChildViewController(barChartClass)
        barChartClass.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 740, 900)
        barChartClass.barChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        barChartClass.barChartView.setScaleEnabled(false)
        self.view.addSubview(barChartClass.view)
        barChartClass.barChartView.legend.enabled = false

        barChartClass.setChartBarGroupDataSet(months, values: unitsSold, values2: unitsSold1, sortIndex: 0)
```

And this is the method call for `setChartBarGroupDataSet`

```
func setChartBarGroupDataSet(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double], values2: [Double],sortIndex:Int)
    {

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count
        {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
            let dataEntry1 = BarChartDataEntry(value: values2[i], xIndex: i)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry1)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: " ")

        let COLOR_SET : [UIColor]!
        COLOR_SET = [UIColor.redColor(),UIColor.greenColor()]

        chartDataSet.setColors(COLOR_SET, alpha: 1.0)

        let dataSets: [BarChartDataSet] = [chartDataSet]

        let data = BarChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSets: dataSets)

        barChartView.data = data

        barChartView.descriptionText = ""

        barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        barChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        barChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false

        barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .EaseInBounce)
    }
```

What I want is something like this

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you manage to center the labels on each bar?

Comment: @JojoNarte I have the same question? Let me know if you have resolved.

Comment: @JojoNarte :- Hi, Please find the answer below, that helped me to solve the issue. Also you can find the answer over gitHub here. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1324

Comment: @Sagar that link doesn't actually show how the values were centered. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a stacked bar chart. In Charts' demos, you can see a stacked bar chart.

Basically, each `BarChartDataEntry` received either one value, or an array of values. Pass in an array of values - and you are good to go!

`let entry = BarChartDataEntry(values: [4.6, 3.8], xIndex: 0)
dataset.colors = [UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.greenColor()]
dataset.stackLabels = ["Inactive inventory", "Active inventory"]`

Answered in the duplicate issue too: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1324

Comment: Thanks for solution, it works. sorry for late reply as I was managing the array for Values dynamically and got succeed in it. thanks for help @daniel.gindi